# Why most of the .NET libraries use Double instead of Decimal? And which one should I use?

Tags: .net, base-class-library

I noticed that many libraries (for example, Math.net, NodaTime, TALib .NET port (library for technical analysis), StackExchange client for Redis db) use Double instead of Decimal. Why is that?

I know Double calculations are faster, but there are problems with precision when using Double, are they not? 
More concrete example - I have a project where I work with conversion rates for currencies and money in general. Source data usually have no more than 4 decimal places (e.g. `54.9320`, and I require at least 6 decimal places for all the calculations. Currently I use decimal everywhere. Am I wrong? Should I switch to double?

Comment: `decimal` is generally for monetary calculations, and `double` is for scientific calculations. Both represent floating-point numbers and thus both have precision issues - they just have different precision characteristics.

Comment: @Enigmativity so if I want precision, I should go with Decimal?

Comment: No, both have precision issues. If you are doing monetary calculations then use `decimal`. If you are doing scientific calculations then use `double`.

Comment: @chester89: It depends on what you do. If you need to exactly represent base-10 numbers (rare, mostly for monetary stuff), then use `decimal`. In most other cases you should use `double`, which is also faster, since it doesn't have to be emulated. Neither is better than the other regarding numeric precision. They're just different.

Comment: Use Double when you don't need precision (exact value). For money or the numbers are an exact representation of a number, you should be used Decimal.

Comment: Since your edit mentions your are dealing with money, **use decimal**. Also, this is pretty much a duplicate of [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/618535/69809).

Answer (score 0):

Normally Decimal is used for everything related to money/price, because Double's accuracy is only 16 decimal digits, in case of large amount, it might be error prone.

```
System.Single > float - 7 digits
System.Double > double - 15-16 digits
System.Decimal > decimal - 28-29 significant digits
```

Now coming to the question of why Libraries uses `Double`, it might be because floating point math operations are natively supported by processors and it uses less memory. While `decimal` type is only more accurate at representing base 10 numbers.

Comment: Two things to note: 1) number of decimals equates to *precision*, not accuracy, and 2) it's neither precision nor accuracy that's the issue, it's the fact that `float`/`double` are represented in base-2 and are not suitable for representing base-10 numbers commonly found in monetary applications.

Comment: Decimal is used for everything related to money/price, not because it is more precise. Even when dealing with the GDP of USA, 15 digits of precision is "to the cent". Clearly economics requiring `decimal` precision we need to step into [Death Star building economics](http://www.shortlist.com/entertainment/films/the-cost-of-the-death-star). No, we use decimal because we are doing decimal (base10) maths.